# Extract Snapdeal star rating for reviews

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping

I am trying to **scrape** reviews and their star ratings for various products from Snapdeal. I am accessing the product through the product URL. On the specific page, I want to filter out ratings according to stars and fetch the rating number as well as review. I am using the following code to do so

'''

```
url_snapdeal=('https://www.snapdeal.com/')

driver.get(url_snapdeal)
time.sleep(2)

search = driver.find_element_by_id('inputValEnter')
search.clear()
search.send_keys('smartphone')
search.send_keys(Keys.ENTER)
time.sleep(2)

for i in range(0,3):
    driver.execute_script('window.scrollTo(0,document.body.scrollHeight)')
    time.sleep(1)

urls=[]

for link in driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//div[@class='product-desc-rating ']/a"):
    urls.append(link.get_attribute('href'))

snap_reviews=[]
snap_ratings=[]

for url in urls:
    driver.get(url)
    time.sleep(4)

    try:
        for x in range(2,7):
            driver.find_element_by_xpath("//div[@class='selectarea']").click()
            time.sleep(1)
            driver.find_element_by_xpath(f"//div[@class='options']/ul/li[{x}]").click()
            time.sleep(1)

            for rating in driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//div[@class='user-review']/div[1]"):
                stars = rating.find_elements_by_xpath("i[@class='sd-icon sd-icon-star active']")
                snap_ratings.append(len(stars))
    
    except NoSuchElementException:
        print('Not found')
```

The try block is supposed to click on the star filter dropdown and select 5star, collect the star rating and review text, again click on the dropdown, click on 4star and collect rating and review, and so on.

My code manages to click on the dropdown but is unable to click on filter options like 5star, 4 star etc. It throws ElementNotInteractable Exception.

Any help or suggestion would be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You actually can get the ratings directly by product number. So get the product numbers and feed that in (I haven't looked, but it might be possible to get those without selenium as well). Then you could just filter the dataframe. Here's and example for 1 product:

```
import requests
import pandas as pd
import math


productId = 639365186960

url = 'https://www.snapdeal.com/acors/web/getSelfieList/v2'
payload = {
    'productId':productId,
    'offset':0}

jsonData = requests.get(url, params=payload).json()
total_pages = math.ceil(jsonData['selfieTotal'] / 10)

for page in range(1,total_pages+1):
    if page == 1:
        ratings = jsonData['selfieList']
    else:
        payload['offset'] = 10*(page-1)
        jsonData = requests.get(url, params=payload).json()
        
        ratings += jsonData['selfieList']


df = pd.DataFrame(ratings)
```

**Output:**

```
df[df['rating'] == 4]
Out[82]: 
                            selfieId  ...                                       reducedImage
0   015cd9a6a1e80000dd22850445ac4f71  ...  https://n1.sdlcdn.com/image/upload/h_162,w_162...
1   015bffb8bcb60000dd22850466cc1c72  ...  https://n1.sdlcdn.com/image/upload/h_162,w_162...
6   015b4dd88df70000dd228504c9271488  ...  https://n1.sdlcdn.com/image/upload/h_162,w_162...
7   015b4dd7f9b80000dd228504b8777fc8  ...  https://n1.sdlcdn.com/image/upload/h_162,w_162...
8   015b1e574cdc0000dd228504d4a694ad  ...  https://n1.sdlcdn.com/image/upload/h_162,w_162...
9   015b182be5640000dd22850418c0bdd6  ...  https://n1.sdlcdn.com/image/upload/h_162,w_162...
10  015aa6e8700e0000dd228504a3378958  ...  https://n1.sdlcdn.com/image/upload/h_162,w_162...
11  015a9df9ab640000dd2285045069dcff  ...  https://n1.sdlcdn.com/image/upload/h_162,w_162...
14  015a4c7a37040000dd2285045daaa6d3  ...  https://n1.sdlcdn.com/image/upload/h_162,w_162...
15  015a4b377b8b0000dd228504d3dd159b  ...  https://n1.sdlcdn.com/image/upload/h_162,w_162...

[10 rows x 9 columns]
```

Comment: Need to do it using Selenium Web Driver only. Is there a way to do with that?

Comment: Yes. Can I ask, why does Selenium need to be used?

Comment: Task criteria I would say. Any suggested modifications in my code to get the job done?

Comment: I’ll take a look at it tomorrow. But ya most likely can be done